# Возможность запрета отправки ARP

Tags: arp

Допустим, есть клиенты и DHCPD. Возможно ли запретить клиентам отправлять arp др клиентам, чтоб не могли смотреть маки друг у друга либо средствами wifi ибо клиенты на wifi'е.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, погуглил и отвечу сам на свой вопрос: выдавать кажодому клиенту под сеть на 4 ip, на шлюзе фильтровать, широковещательные запросы ходить не будут.

Comment: костыль же.. очень усложняет сеть

Answer (score 1):

Средствами WiFi можно изолировать клиентов. В микротиках нужно снять галочку default forward в настройках точки доступа. В AirOS поставить галочку client isolation. ap_isolate=1 параметр используется в hostapd. isolate=yes в конфигурацию интерфейса нужно поместить для openwrt.

Answer (score 0):

Нет нельзя. ARP - 2й уровень OSI, поэтому классифицировать как-либо кроме как по MAC адресу фрейм нельзя, хотя изврат он везде изврат. Более того, зачем это вам? Клиенты тогда не смогут работать друг с другом, вы этого добиваетесь? А возможность 100% взломать WEP и, в зависимости от пароля, WPA2-PSK, все равно останется.

Comment: Да, именно мне нужно, чтоб клиенты друг другу не могли передавать данные и с ppptp не хочется замачиваться. Шифрования нет на wifi, аутентификация по маку, но скорее всего придется писать по паролю, тк маки всем видны.